# I am not able to connect to mySql db in elixir when i run mix ecto.create

Tags: mysql, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have replaced the `postgrex` dependency with `{:myxql, ">= 0.0.0"}` and now I"m getting this error:

```
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {:postgrex, {'no such file or directory', 'postgrex.app'}}}
    (ecto_sql 3.8.3) lib/ecto/adapters/postgres.ex:308: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.run_query/2
    (ecto_sql 3.8.3) lib/ecto/adapters/postgres.ex:159: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.storage_up/1
    (ecto 3.8.4) lib/mix/tasks/ecto.create.ex:53: anonymous fn/3 in Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Create.run/1
    (elixir 1.13.4) lib/enum.ex:937: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
    (mix 1.13.4) lib/mix/task.ex:397: anonymous fn/3 in Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix 1.13.4) lib/mix/cli.ex:84: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
```

Comment: Have you deleted your `YourApp.Repo` module? This file usually contains `adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres`, which you don't need anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the right adapter for your Repo.

Your application is still trying to use the `Ecto.Adapters.Postgres` adapter that was the default when you generated the app.
In your `lib/app/repo.ex`, change the adapter to `Ecto.Adapters.MyXQL`.

You can find documentation related to Ecto SQL adapters here : https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html